# Format a timespan with up to two fields

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, formatting

I'm looking to achieve a time format that looks like this: **2d 4h** remaining; or **1h 36m** remaining; or **35s** remaining, etc. So that it only displays the two largest values of time (this is how Clash of Clans and some other mobile games format wait times.)

Currently my code is below, but I'm wondering if there might be a shorter way to format the timespan in this manner? I'm not fully sure if `String.Format` will work…

```
public string FormatRushTime ( System.TimeSpan span )
{
    string t1;
    string t2;
    if ( span.Days > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%d") + "d";
        t2 = span.Hours > 0 ? span.ToString("%h") + "h" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Hours > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%h") + "h";
        t2 = span.Minutes > 0 ? span.ToString("%m") + "m" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Minutes > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%m") + "m";
        t2 = span.Seconds > 0 ? span.ToString("%s") + "s" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Seconds > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%s") + "s";
        t2 = String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        t1 = String.Empty;
        t2 = String.Empty;
    }

    return t1+" "+t2;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want to do, is use early-returns (FTW). Also, let the formatter do the string work for you. Right tool for the job.

Consider your code, [rewritten in Ideone...](http://ideone.com/NhIbfL):

```
static string FormatRushTime (TimeSpan span)
{
    if ( span.Days != 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}d {1:d}h", span.Days, Math.Abs(span.Hours));
    }
    if ( span.Hours != 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}h {1:d}m", span.Hours, Math.Abs(span.Minutes));
    }
    if ( span.Minutes != 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}m {1:d}s", span.Minutes, Math.Abs(span.Seconds));
    }
    return String.Format("{0:d}s", span.Seconds);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rolfl — This is nice and easy to read. Although I would like to ignore the second value if it's 0 (e.g., **2h 0m** -> **2h**). Is this possible, perhaps with a ternary operator?

Comment: Yes, it can be ignored with the ternary, but I would actually advise you against removing the 0-values (and I intentionally did it this way). The reason is precision, in a count-down, 5m 2s, 5m 1s, 5m is 'just wrong' because 5m could be a lot more than 5m 0s. Still, the ternary is your friend.

Comment: You're right. It would look odd. Unfortunately I am not always counting down… sometimes I just want to display the wait time, and then a 0-value looks odd. I re-posted as a new question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52635/function-for-formatting-a-timespan-with-optional-trailing-zero

Comment: Good use of `!=` here rather than OP's `>`.

Answer (score 5):

I love LINQ so I present two solutions.

```
public static string FormatRushTime(System.TimeSpan span)
{
    var time = new[] 
        {
            new { Unit = "d", Value = span.Days },
            new { Unit = "h", Value = span.Hours},
            new { Unit = "m", Value = span.Minutes},
            new { Unit = "s", Value = span.Seconds}
        };

    var filtred = time.SkipWhile(t => t.Value == 0)
                      .Take(2)
                      .Where(t => t.Value != 0)
                      .Select(t => String.Format("{0}{1} ", t.Value, t.Unit));

    return String.Concat(filtred);
}
```

I'm not sure if it's readable beacause I'm pretty tired. :)

```
public static string FormatRushTime(System.TimeSpan span)
{
    string[] units = { "d", "h", "m", "s" };

    var r = units.Select(unit => new { Unit = unit, Value = span.ToString("%" + unit) })
                 .SkipWhile(time => time.Value == "0")
                 .Take(2)
                 .Where(time => time.Value != "0")
                 .Select(time => String.Format("{0}{1} ", time.Value, time.Unit));

    return string.Concat(r);
}
```

Comment: The trailing space isn't nice. I would instead drop the space from the `Format()` and used `string.Join()` instead of `Concat()`.

Comment: This is a clever, though I find rolfl's easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can take advantage of [custom format strings for `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287). Modifying rolfl's answer to use those, it could look something like:

```
public static string FormatRushTime(TimeSpan span)
{
    var result = span.ToString(GetRushTimeFormat(span));

    if (span < TimeSpan.Zero)
        result = "-" + result;

    return result;
}

private static string GetRushTimeFormat(TimeSpan span)
{
    if (span.Days != 0)
        return @"d\d\ h\h";

    if (span.Hours != 0)
        return @"h\h\ m\m";

    if (span.Minutes != 0)
        return @"m\m\ s\s";

    return @"s\s";
}
```