# Function for formatting a timespan with optional trailing zero

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking to achieve a time format that looks like this: **2d 4h** remaining; or **1h 36m** remaining; or **35s** remaining, etc. So that it only displays the two largest values of time (this is how Clash of Clans and some other mobile games format wait times.)

I would like to format the wait time value as simply **5h** or **5h 0m** depending on whether I am displaying the total wait time or currently counting down. My code is below… But is there a slightly simpler way of writing it without so many returns?

(This question was originally asked here:
[Is there a simpler way to format this timespan?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52622/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-format-this-timespan) )

```
public string FormatRushTime ( System.TimeSpan span, boolean removeZeros )
{
    if ( span.Days > 0 )
    {
        if ( span.Hours > 0 || !removeZeros )
            return String.Format("{0:d}d {1:d}h", span.Days, span.Hours);
        else
            return String.Format("{0:d}d", span.Days);
    }
    if ( span.Hours > 0 )
    {
        if ( span.Minutes > 0 || !removeZeros )
            return String.Format("{0:h}h {1:m}m", span.Hours, span.Minutes);
        else
            return String.Format("{0:h}h", span.Hours);
    }
    if ( span.Minutes > 0 )
    {
        if ( span.Seconds > 0 || !removeZeros )
            return String.Format("{0:m}m {1:s}s", span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
        else
            return String.Format("{0:m}m", span.Minutes);
    }
    return String.Format("{0:d}s", span.Seconds);
}
```

Comment: It is curious code did not employ the [good answer's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52627/29485) use of `!=`, rather than `>`.  Here code relies on the span being positive.  A wider application function would also handle negative time spans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to reduce returns, you could use a single `string.Format` call and not make use of additional arguments in certain cases:

```
// Changed removeZeroes to includeZeroes since it read kind of like a double negative.
string format = includeZeros ? "{0:d}d {1:d}h" : "{0:d}d";

// span.Hours will not get used if there's nowhere to put it in the format string:
return string.Format(format, span.Days, span.Hours);
```

Comment: I like this solution the best. I didn't realize String.Format would ignore secondary variables if they were missing. This reduces the size but keeps it easily understandable. :)

Answer (score 5):

This code is right on the tipping-point between abstracting the values to a loop, and manually unwinding the loop. To show what I mean, this is a different way of writing the function:

```
private static readonly string[] oneformats = {"{0:d}d", "{0:d}h", "{0:d}m", "{0:d}s"};
private static readonly string[] twoformats = {"{0:d}d {1:d}h", "{0:d}h {1:d}m", "{0:d}m {1:d}s"};

static string FormatRushTime (TimeSpan span, bool reportZero )
{
    int[] times = new int[]{span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds};
    for (int i = 0; i < times.Length; i++)
    {
        if (times[i] != 0)
        {
            if (((i + 1) < times.Length) && (times[i+1] != 0 || reportZero))
            {
                return String.Format(twoformats[i], times[i], times[i+1]);
            }
            return String.Format(oneformats[i], times[i]);
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

In essence, it looks in order through the array of times, and then makes a decision on whether to print just one, or the next sub-time as well.

In this way, your code overhead in terms of setting up the array, is more, but the code structure is a 'simple' loop, and does not have any 'magic' properties.

I have it running with some [simple test data on ideone](http://ideone.com/IxKDXf).

Answer (score 3):

I see you reposted. My solution from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/52666

```
public static string FormatRushTime(System.TimeSpan span, bool removeZeroes)
{
    var time = new[] 
        {
            new { Unit = "d", Value = span.Days },
            new { Unit = "h", Value = span.Hours},
            new { Unit = "m", Value = span.Minutes},
            new { Unit = "s", Value = span.Seconds}
        };

    var filtred = time.SkipWhile(t => t.Value == 0)                             // Skip until zero values 
                      .Take(2)                                                  // How many units take
                      .Where(t => ! removeZeroes || t.Value != 0)               // Show zero values?        
                      .Select(t => String.Format("{0}{1} ", t.Value, t.Unit));

    return String.Concat(filtred);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution.

In this solution I'm pushing all of the formatted time segments onto a stack.
Then, I pop up any leading zero entries from the stack.  Once I've cleared the leading zeros I then grab the top two (if they exist) from the stack and use those checking for zero on the second one.  I put the two selected time segments into a length two array that is used to build the final formatted string.

This solution avoids the multi-faceted if blocks.  It could be made more readable by defining your own struct to hold the time segment value and formatted string instead of the Tuple.

```
private string FormatRushTime( TimeSpan dt, bool includeZeros ) {

string[] dispSegments = new[] {string.Empty, "0s"};

    // Only do the work if there's an actual time span value passed in
if (dt.TotalSeconds > 0) {

            // Push the time segments from the TimeSpan onto a stack along with their
            // related string format
    Stack<Tuple<int, string>> timeSegments = new Stack<Tuple<int, string>>();

    PushTimeSegment( timeSegments, dt.Seconds, "s" );
    PushTimeSegment( timeSegments, dt.Minutes, "m" );
    PushTimeSegment( timeSegments, dt.Hours, "h" );
    PushTimeSegment( timeSegments, dt.Days, "d" );

    int takenSegments = 0;  // The number of segments already found

    // Clear out leading zeros
    while (timeSegments.Peek().Item1 == 0) {
        timeSegments.Pop();
    }

            // Get the first two segments from the stack
    while (timeSegments.Count > 0 && takenSegments < 2) {
        Tuple<int, string> tuple = timeSegments.Pop();
        if (tuple.Item1 > 0 || includeZeros) {
            dispSegments[takenSegments] = tuple.Item2;
            takenSegments++;
        }
    }
}
return string.Format( "{0} {1}", dispSegments[0], dispSegments[1] ).Trim();
}

private static void PushTimeSegment( Stack<Tuple<int, string>> timeSegments, int timePeriod, string timeDelimiter ) {
timeSegments.Push( new Tuple<int, string>( timePeriod, string.Format( "0:d}{1}", timePeriod, timeDelimiter ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Please give some explanation of what you did, it helps make this a review

Comment: Please see my edited answer.  Hopefully that explains it well enough.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hmm, Does this work well when the time span is < 60 seconds like 0d, 0h, 0m, 1s?